# how to represent a circuit when a simplified expression is just 1 or 0?

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, logic-gates

For example if my boolean expression is defined by the function f(x,y)= x+xyz+yzx'+wx''+w'x+x'y+1. I know that A+1=1 no matter how A is. But if they ask me to represent the circuit with logic gates, what is the representation of it? I mean they generally ask me to simplify the expression in order to optimize the circuit. So how can I proceed?

Comment: Just a "1" or "0" near the end of a wire ought to do it. Or a ground or Vdd symbol if your drawing is showing things more physically.

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question, or are you asking something else?

Comment: @Trevor well, I don't know the representation in a diagram of a 1 or a 0. I'm a newbi in electronics trying to understand logic gates for my logic class.

Answer (score 4):

that is easy, both these methods are correct

[image]

Comment: what if the result is a 0?

Comment: write a '0' instead of the '1' in the picture, the other usual way is to draw the ground symbol where Vcc is present in the picture.

Answer (score 2):

1 is logic HIGH, logic HIGH is VCC (supply voltage).
A is a wire on which the value of A is propagated. So

$$ A + 1 = 1 $$

is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFm8jc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

which is just

$$ 1 $$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZBgPk.png)</sup>

---

If the result is 0 then the logic LOW, aka the ground reference would be the signal.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNZBCq.png)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to actually show the inputs though as well as the outputs. It makes it clearer that the logic has considered those inputs despite the output being fixed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRvKT4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It is also normal to show somewhere what you want the ONE or ZERO to be connected to... for example.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCFIKC.png)</sup>